# Ruby: split one hash into two based on desired keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm hoping this question has a very simple answer. I can think of ways to do with with boring, annoying looping, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution.

If I have the following two variables:

```
hash = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3, :d => 4}
keyset = [:a, :c]
```

How can I get the following two hashes in the simplest way possible?

```
hash1 = {:a => 1, :c => 3}
hash2 = {:b => 3, :d => 4}
```

If the example doesn't make my goal clear, in essence, what I want is a hybrid between `#delete` and `#delete_if` - `#delete` returns the deleted value, whereas `#delete_if` allows me to delete in bulk. I would prefer a way to delete in bulk, and have the deleted values returned - or something equivalent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try Active Support with [`Hash#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) and/or [`Hash#except`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except).  The bang methods also exist:

```
$ irb
>> require 'active_support/core_ext'
=> true

>> hash = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3, :d => 4}
=> {:a=>1, :d=>4, :b=>2, :c=>3}
>> keyset = [:a, :c]
=> [:a, :c]

>> remainders = hash.slice!(*keyset)
=> {:d=>4, :b=>2}

>> remainders
=> {:d=>4, :b=>2}
>> hash
=> {:a=>1, :c=>3}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
hash = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }
keyset = [:a, :c]

left, right = hash.partition {|k,v| keyset.include? k }
```

This leaves left and right as arrays of arrays; turn back into hash:

```
left = Hash[left]
right = Hash[right]

puts "left=#{left.inspect}"
puts "right=#{right.inspect}"
```

Comment: It seems like a design flaw of Ruby that `.partition` isn't the answer by itself; given that `Hash#select` and `Hash#reject` return hashes, it would make sense for `Hash#partition` to return an array of two hashes. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: If you want to get a hash back (in Ruby 2.0+) you can do `left, right = hash.partition{ |k, v| keyset.include?(k) }.map(&:to_h)`

Answer (score 13):

```
new_hash = {}
keyset.each {|i| new_hash[i] = hash.delete(i)}
```

That seemed to do it for me, without pulling in extra requirements

Comment: I didn't mention that I was on Rails - since it seemed irrelevant - but that means I already have Active Support. But thanks, still! :)

Answer (score 10):

With Rails/Active Support you can use the `extract!` method:

```
hash = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3, :d => 4}
keyset = [:a, :c]

hash2 = hash.extract! *keyset
>> {:a=>1, :c=>3}

hash
>> {:b=>2, :d=>4}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind external dependencies you can use https://github.com/renra/split-off-ruby Then you can do:

```
hash2 = hash.split_off!(:b, :d)
```

hash will still contain the original values for keys :a and :c. The above methods are good enough, but sometimes it's better to be expressive about your intent with the right method name, I believe.